# Eclipse wait forever when rename a script file on drive and updates on eclipse

Tags: google-apps-script, google-eclipse-plugin

When using Google Apps Script plugin on Eclipse, if I rename a file on the web interface and try to "Update Apps Script from Drive" in the eclipse Google context menu, it start waiting forever and block eclipse. I need to force quit, restart eclipse, delete the project and import again to see the updated project with the renamed file.

Any idea whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the Apps Script feature of GPE. We are now working on a fix. Sorry for the inconvenience, and thank you for your report.